# How to send a pre-built request

Tags: javascript, user-interface, interface, customization

What I want:
I'm using a website (that I wish to remain anonymous) to buy securities. It is quite complex and as far as I can see coded in JavaScript. 
What I would like to do with this website is to 'inject' a request to buy something from a separate process. So instead of having to search for what I want to buy manually and get in there and manually fill out the form, click buy and confirm the 'are you sure you want to place the order?' popup I would just like to send whatever command/request is being sent to the server when the confirm-button is pressed directly.

To be extra clear: I simply don't want to go through the manual hassle but rather just send a pre-built request with the necessary parameters embedded.
I'm certainly not looking to do anything malicious, just make my order input faster and smoother. It is not necessary to automate login or anything like that.

I understand that this is not much to go on but I'm throwing it out there and ask the question: Can it be done?
I really don't know how this stuff works behind the scenes, maybe the request is somehow encrypted to some custom format that is next to impossible to reverse engineer, or maybe not.

Comment: So you want to bypass the websites controls and hit their endpoints directly? Unless the site has a public API I believe what your asking for is a bit unethical.

Comment: Yes, I guess that is what I am trying to do. They have no Public API. Maybe you are right, but I don't really see from a user perspective how it is unethical, like I said, I'm only trying to make my workflow smoother. Maybe this is considered very unethical, I don't know, like I said I have little experience with these things.

Comment: @Tottish  for such things you can use any web sniffer or developer tools available in any major browser, on a network grid you can see all requests with parameters and then use this requests with other parameters, the answer of Michael is pretty accurate for what you is searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Injecting" is probably the wrong term.  Most people will think of sql injection or javascript injection which is usually malicious activity.  That doesn't seem to be what you want.

What you are looking for is an automation tool.  There are plenty of tools available.  Try a google search for "web automation tool." Selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/ and PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/ are popular ones.

Additionally, you may be able to recreate the request that is actually buying the security.  If you use Chrome you can open Developer Tools and look at what appears on the Network tab as you go through the site. Firefox and Edge have similar tools as well. When you make the purchase you will see the actual network request that placed it.  Then, depending on how the site is implemented you may just be able to replicate that request using a tool like Postman.

However before you do any of the above, I would recommend that you take a look at the TOS for the site you mention.  They may specifically prohibit that kind of activity.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That is very helpful. I had no ideas such developed automation tools existed. Good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

I want to elaborate my comment and Michael Ratliff answer.

On example.

We got some services. The administration of this services could be done via web-interface. But only in manual mode, there is no API (yes, 2016 year and no API). So at first there was not much work with administration and we done it manually.

But time passed and the amount of administration work grow exponentially so we come to situation where this work must be automated (still no API even few new versions was released).

What have we done:

We opened pages we need in browser, open *Inspect Element* (in Firefox), open *Network*, fill the web-form, press button we need. In the left part we see all requests to service, by pressing any request on the right side appears full description of what was send/get, all requests and their parameters. Then we took that parameters, change them and send back to server. Kind of reverse-engineering though.

For automation we used PHP and CURL. For now almost all work with the services is automated.

And yes, we have used Selenium (before PHP and CURL). You can open form you need. Press *Rec* do some stuff on the web-form, Selenium collects this data and then you can change parameters in Selenium script and re-run it.